# why is the Artifactory CE service Port is not the configured Port?

Tags: artifactory

the default port of UI is **8081** for  Artifactory CE ,

but In my server ,the **8081** is used by another service ,

so I add  :

```
artifactory:

  port: 8083
```

in jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml

then restart the Antifactory CE

but if I acess http://IP:**8083**/ui/, I get : HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

If I access http://174.34.90.112:**8082**/ui , then it seems OK

and in "Set Me Up",

it shows : conan remote add  http://IP:**8040**/artifactory/api/conan/conan

but the IP:**8040** is **not** work ,

I need to use  IP:**8083**  to upload the pacakges

how can I configure the Port right?
or how to keep the UI and the system.yaml  consistency ?

Comment: Usually, the parameter which affects the set me up is the custom base URL:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/General+System+Settings
Can you check this one?
Also, 8083 is a port used directly by Artifactory which is intended to bypass the Router service (used by port 8082), if you want to test it correctly, you may want to use this end point:
curl HTTP://IP:8083/artifactory/api/system/ping
Do you have a reverse proxy in front of Artifactory as well? We might need also to make modifications there if you have changed the port.

Answer (score -1):

In artifacroty version 7.*, the UI has a different port then the service, this is why you are able to get to the ui in port 8082.

Regarding the service port, it may be that you have another formating problem that causes artifactory not to pick the new port configuration.
Usually, these kind of errors are written to the console.log file.
Did you check the log file for configuration errors?
Can you upload the entire system.yaml?

Comment: this is the entire system.yaml

```
configVersion: 1
shared:
    security:

    node:

    database:

        type: mariadb
        driver: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
        url: "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/artdb?characterEncoding=UTF-8&elideSetAutoCommits=true&useSSL=false"
        username: artifactory1
        password: xxyyzz
artifactory:
    port: 8083
```

Comment: Sorry ,  I cannot  edit it as good format the system.yaml